# SQL - query Order Header and Order Detail without Duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, data-modeling

Attempting to query an Order Header and Detail table to sum results by Month and am encountering a data model limitation. Essentially I want to audit our ETL processes to ensure the Header-level data is correctly aggregated from the Detail level. The TRANS_ID key field represents one order, so naturally the Detail table will have several rows per TRANS_ID.

Table ORDER_HEADER has (for ease of illustration):

```
TRANS_ID
TRANS_DT (DD-MON-YY)
PROFIT
```

Table ORDER_DETAIL has:

```
TRANS_ID
TRANS_LINE_NO
LINE_ITM_PROFIT
```

The question I want to answer is: at the month level what is the total profit from the Header and what is the total profit from the Detail? My results should have three columns: "Month of TRANS_DT", "HDR Profit", and "DTL Profit"

If I inner join on ORDER_HEADER.TRANS_ID = ORDER_DETAIL.TRANS_ID and GROUP BY "Month of ORDER_HEADER.TRANS_DT" then I will obviously duplicate the Header values.

My data volume (in an Oracle RDBMS) is about 150MM Header records and upwards of 600MM Detail records, so the best solution would NOT sum the entire Detail table to the "TRANS_ID" level before joining to the Header.

Answer (score 0):

Do this with aggregations in subqueries:

```
select oh.yyyymm, oh.hdr_profit, od.dtl_profit
from (select to_char(trans_dt, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, sum(profit) as hdr_profit 
      from order_header
      group by to_char(trans_dt, 'YYYY-MM')
     ) oh join
     (select to_char(oh.trans_dt, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
             sum(od.line_itm_profit) as dtl_profit 
      from order_header oh join
           order_detail od
           on oh.trans_id = od.trans_id
      group by to_char(oh.trans_dt, 'YYYY-MM')
     ) od
     on oh.yyyymm = od.yyyymm;
```

Comment: It seems to me that it will be better if order_header has two different aliases in different places ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some small corrections to Gordon's solution.
Pay attention - here there will be only monthes from ORDER_HEADER table.

```
select oh.TRANS_MONTH "Month of TRANS_DT", oh.PROFIT "HDR Profit", od.PROFIT "DTL Profit"
from
(
select TO_CHAR(TRANS_DT, 'YYYY-MM') TRANS_MONTH , SUM(LINE_ITM_PROFIT) PROFIT
from ORDER_HEADER
group by TO_CHAR(TRANS_DT, 'YYYY-MM')
) oh
left join 
(
select TO_CHAR(TRANS_DT, 'YYYY-MM') TRANS_MONTH, SUM(LINE_ITM_PROFIT) PROFIT
from ORDER_DETAIL od
where TRANS_ID in (select TRANS_ID from ORDER_HEADER)
group by TO_CHAR(TRANS_DT, 'YYYY-MM')
) od
on oh.TRANS_MONTH = od.TRANS_MONTH
```

Comment: Will the "od" query not be expensive? Further more I am assuming that all child Detail records have a valid Header parent record, so that might render `TRANS_ID in (select TRANS_ID from ORDER_HEADER)` moot

Comment: You wrote 'the best solution would NOT sum the entire Detail table to the "TRANS_ID" level before joining to the Header', so I guess that there are records in ORDER_DETAIL table which don't have corresponding in ORDER_HEADER.